# Plugin.FacebookClient do nothing after posting to Facebook

Tags: c#, android, facebook, xamarin

I'm new to Xamarin, and I'm developing an app in PCL (Xamarin.Forms) which includes login and post using Facebook. I'm using [Plugin.FacebookClient](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FacebookClientPlugin) for cross-platform development. I try to post a picture with caption, whether I had the Facebook app installed or not, the post completed and I can see the post from my browser (as a friend of the account I used to post). I need to show a message after post to my app, but when the post completed, nothing happens. no logs, no return message. When the post canceled or got into error, I got the console logs and the message in my app. My code for sharing:

```
            private IFacebookClient _facebookService = CrossFacebookClient.Current;

            private async Task<string> PostFb(byte[] data, string text)
    {
        try
        {
            string postMessage = string.Empty;
            FacebookSharePhoto photo = new FacebookSharePhoto(text, data);
            FacebookSharePhoto[] photos = new FacebookSharePhoto[] { photo };
            FacebookSharePhotoContent photoContent = new FacebookSharePhotoContent(photos, null, text);
            Console.WriteLine("Uploading...");
            var result = await _facebookService.ShareAsync(photoContent);

            _facebookService.OnSharing += (s, a) =>
            {
                switch (a.Status)
                {
                    case FacebookActionStatus.Completed:
                        postMessage = "Completed";
                        break;

                    case FacebookActionStatus.Canceled:
                        postMessage = "Canceled";
                        break;

                    case FacebookActionStatus.Unauthorized:
                        postMessage = result.Message;
                        break;

                    case FacebookActionStatus.Error:
                        postMessage = result.Message;
                        break;
                }
            };
            return postMessage;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Post FB: " + ex.ToString());
        }
        return "Something's wrong";
    }
```

I without using the event handler before, but still nothing happened. Nothing show in try catch either. My app didn't freeze, just didn't do anything. My code for calling that function:

```
            string postFbmessage = await PostFb(imageArray, Message);
            UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("FacebookPost message: " + postFbmessage);
            Console.WriteLine("FacebookPost message: " + postFbmessage);
```

I did try searching in GitHub issues, but it said the issues already fixed. I deleted the app cache, clean the build, retrying, but still, nothing happened. Can anyone tell me where did things go wrong? I'm sorry for the bad English, I hope you can understand what I'm implying.

**Edit:** It was [this one](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FacebookClientPlugin/issues/82), where they already merged the fix. Thank you for reminding me Jason

Comment: "it said the issues already fixed" - which issue?  If you found a but that appears to be related it helps to link to that specific issue so we can see it

Comment: @Jason I edited the question. I understand the issue as I got the same but still didn't know what to do to fix it.

Comment: This is fixed in the pre-release version of the nuget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Jason for reminding me in the comment section. They did fix the issues, but it's still in the [pre-release version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.FacebookClient/3.0.7-beta). I updated my NuGet package and no issues.